# Datagrid textbox cell validation-vb.net

Tags: vb.net, validation, datagridviewtextboxcell

I am having a datagrid.  In the First Row, First Column of the datagrid, I am trying to get employees code using "Autocompletionsearch string" method ("Edit control event").  When i leave the current cell, it must validate the value selected.  I having the problem, the value of the current cell is empty.  Kindly help
Which datagrid event should i use here in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

You can validate using the CellEndEdit event. You can find more info here...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit(v=vs.110).aspx